# Customization of UIBarButtonItem and interface rotations

Tags: ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

There are a lot of talks about customization of `UIBarButtonItem` with custom view as an UIButton. It's quite clear. What I didn't find so far though, and what surprises me, is that there is no mentioning for custom UIBarButtonItems which handle interface rotations - its a common behavior when you rotate an iPhone, bar buttons get squeezed vertically. However, if you customize UIBarButtonItem in ordinary way (by calling `initWithCustomView:` method), it will stay non-squeezed after rotating into landscape orientation. Are there any workarounds for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found solution with handling `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` in custom `UIBarButtonItem` class pretty decent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rebuild the UIBarButtonItem (Your Custom UIButton) with new orientation image and text, or reset the frame of custom view.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    UIButton *rightItemButton = (UIButton *)self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView;
    //resize the frame
    if (isLandscape) {

    } else if (isPortrait) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean change button's properties from `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` method of view controller? to my opinion its very ugly from code design point of view - view controllers has enough work to do besides adjusting buttons which are custom views of barbuttons which are children of uinavigationitem which is placed on uinvaigationbar - insane! i hope apple has better workaround for this...

Comment: yes, because that's your custom view, you should control it by yourself, also you can override the - (void)layoutSubviews in your ViewControllers for reset the size and position of any subviews

Comment: well, yeah, i agree.. but still, in my opinion such fine-tunes restrain us from using "good" code design - for instance, in this case i see more logical to design such a bar button which will totally autonomous and handle its' contents on its own. and i think particularly this situation could be solved if apple provide any kind of `didAdjustFrameForNewOrientation:` call or smth like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add the UIBarButtonItem from IB (you don't have to create it programatically) you can set the springs and struts to get your default behaviour. This solution worked for me.

Comment: hm. there is just width and image insets can be customized. but anyway, what if there is a need in an `UIBarButtonItem` with custom view as i stated in question? (its my case)

Comment: The thing is if you want a custom UIBarButton in your navigation bar from IB, you can drag a UIBarButtonItem on the navigation bar, after that drag a UIButton inside the UIBarButtonItem, then you can customise as you like the UIButton(background, title, etc). For your case I think you can create a custom UIView that has a button(or other views) inside it and also set the spring and struts to get your behaviour. NOTE: I didn't test this case but I don't see any reason why this can't work.

Comment: hm, that looks like could work if you have an `UINavigationController` in your xib. however, its not my case. but thanks anyway for the hint!